# Add Icon to material-table "lookup" (material-ui React)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I use material-ui for my project and material-table for data tables.
I am wondering to know, how can I use custom render (ex. add an icon) in **column -> lookup**.
for example from material-table documentation:

```
columns={[
        {
          title: 'Birth Place',
          field: 'birthCity',
          lookup: { 34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa' },
        },
      ]}
```

*it is here simple key-value as string. I want to add an icon to each value*

something like this:

[image: sth like this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per their code of renderLookUpFiled method, [React.Element](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html) as a value of lookup object should work.
They are rendering `{this.props.columnDef.lookup[key]}` this means if we pass [React.Element](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html), it will render that as well, there might be some props warning but it should work

```
columns={[
        {
          title: 'Birth Place',
          field: 'birthCity',
          lookup: { 34: <div><img src="/your/image"/> İstanbul</div>, 63: <div><icon/> Şanlıurfa</div> },
        },
      ]}
```

[image]
Code of renderLookUpFiled method from Material-table
[image: Above code Output]

Comment: this render works just for **row Rendering** and not for lookup. For example, Birth Place [here](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/editable)

Comment: Ahhh, as per the code, you can pass the React.Element in value to render anything, let me update the answer,

Comment: @s.d.fard I have updated the answer and verified the recommended change, it is working fine at my end